# View objects are not showing in code. I'm making a Custom Dialog

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, customdialog

```
open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false
private lateinit var mProgressDialog: Dialog

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val binding = ActivityBaseBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

}


fun showProgressDialog(text: String) {
    mProgressDialog = Dialog(this)
    mProgressDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_progress)
    mProgressDialog.tv_progress_text.text = text

    mProgressDialog.show()



}
```

}

//This is my XML file for custom Dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/tv_progress_text"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_progress_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="@string/pleaseWait"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/progressBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my code(kotlin) and im using view binding. I'm not able to access view objects from custom dialog xml file in function showProgressDialog. However, i have tried to make a binding instance for custom dialog in fun showProgressDialog but that is also not working. Can anyone tell me, what is the problem and how i should access the view objects form custom Dialog xml file. setContentView is also of no use.

Answer (score 0):

For using view binding with your custom dialog, you have to inflate your custom dialog with its generated methods, you cannot directly use it.

As you haven't written the name of your custom dialog layout file, I assume it to be `customDialog.xml`. Now you can inflate and show this custom dialog using this.

```
fun showProgressDialog(text: String) {
    mProgressDialog = Dialog(this)
    val customDialogBinding = CustomDialogBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, binding.root, false)
    mProgressDialog.setContentView(customDialogBinding.root)
    customDialogBinding.tv_progress_text.text = text
    mProgressDialog.show()
}
```